# Rspec raise matcher not working, copied syntax from docs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

```
rspec-core (3.9.1)
rspec-expectations (3.9.0)
rspec-mocks (3.9.1)
rspec-rails (4.0.0.beta4, 3.9.0)
rspec-support (3.9.2)
```

According to docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-9/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher, this should work:

```
expect { raise StandardError }.to raise_error
```

Yet in my code, when I run JUST that spec by itself, I get:

```
Failures:

  1) time rules should work
     Failure/Error: expect(raise StandardError).to raise_error
     
     StandardError:
       StandardError
     # ./spec/models/time_rules_spec.rb:87:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Works for me, and I don't remember having issues with this matcher. Maybe you can it on a fresh project, with no other gems maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely at the error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(raise StandardError).to raise_error
```

That indicates that your failing test looks like this:

```
it '...' do
  expect(raise StandardError).to raise_error
end
```

when it should look like this:

```
it '...' do
  expect { raise StandardError }.to raise_error
end
```

Your version is equivalent to:

```
result = raise StandardError
expect(result).to raise_error
```

so the `raise` is triggered before `raise_error` can trap and check for the exception. If you pass a block to `expect` as in the documentation:

```
expect { raise StandardError }.to raise_error
```

then the `raise_error` matcher will have everything set up to trap and check for the exception.

---

As an aside, you'll probably want to be more explicit with your `raise_error` matcher:

```
expect { raise StandardError }.to raise_error(StandardError)
```

to avoid an overly-broad matcher and a warning like this:

> WARNING: Using the `raise_error` matcher without providing a specific error or message risks false positives, since `raise_error` will match when Ruby raises a `NoMethodError`, `NameError` or `ArgumentError`, potentially allowing the expectation to pass without even executing the method you are intending to call.